# What is the default behavior of perf record?

Tags: linux, perf

It's clear to me that `perf` always records one or more events, and the sampling can be counter-based or time-based. But when the `-e` and `-F` switches are not given, what is the default behavior of `perf record`? The manpage for `perf-record` doesn't tell you what it does in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default event is `cycles`, as can be seen by running `perf script` after `perf record`. There, you can also see that the default sampling behavior is time-based, since the number of cycles is not constant. The default frequency is 4000 Hz, which can be seen in the [source code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.12.8/source/tools/perf/builtin-record.c#L2387) and checked by comparing the file size or number of samples to a recording where `-F 4000` was specified.

The [perf wiki](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Period_and_rate) says that the rate is 1000 Hz, but this is not true anymore for kernels newer than 3.4.

Comment: Sometimes when there is PEBS/IBS in cpu, event `cycles:pp` (or :ppp for skid regulation) may be used by default. Recent man page  https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-record.1.html documents it as  "*If there is no -e specified in perf record, on hybrid platform, it creates two default cycles and adds them to event list. One is for core, the other is for atom.*". P modifier described in man perf-list https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-list.1.html#EVENT_MODIFIERS "The p modifier can be used for specifying how precise the instruction address should be."

Answer (score 2):

Default event selection in `perf record` is done in user-space perf tool which is usually distributed as part of linux kernel. With `make perf-src-tar-gz`  from linux kernel source dir we can make tar gz for quick rebuild or download such tar from https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/tools/perf. There are also several online "LXR" cross-reference viewers for linux kernel source which can be used just like grep to learn about perf internals.

There is the function to select default event list (evlist) for perf record: [`__perf_evlist__add_default` of tools/perf/util/evlist.c file](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/tools/perf/util/evlist.c#L213):

```
int __perf_evlist__add_default(struct evlist *evlist, bool precise)
{
    struct evsel *evsel = perf_evsel__new_cycles(precise);
    evlist__add(evlist, evsel);
    return 0;
}
```

Called from perf record implementation in case of zero events parsed from options: [tools/perf/builtin-record.c: `int cmd_record()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/tools/perf/builtin-record.c#L2414)

```
rec->evlist->core.nr_entries == 0 &&
    __perf_evlist__add_default(rec->evlist, !record.opts.no_samples)
```

And [`perf_evsel__new_cycles`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/tools/perf/util/evsel.c#L295) will ask for **hardware event cycles** (PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE + PERF_COUNT_HW_CPU_CYCLES) with optional kernel sampling, and **max precise** ([check modifiers in man perf-list](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-list.1.html#EVENT_MODIFIERS), it is EIP sampling skid workarounds using PEBS or IBS):

```
struct evsel *perf_evsel__new_cycles(bool precise)
{
    struct perf_event_attr attr = {
        .type   = PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        .config = PERF_COUNT_HW_CPU_CYCLES,
        .exclude_kernel = !perf_event_can_profile_kernel(),
    };
    struct evsel *evsel;

    /*
     * Now let the usual logic to set up the perf_event_attr defaults
     * to kick in when we return and before perf_evsel__open() is called.
     */
    evsel = evsel__new(&attr);
    evsel->precise_max = true;

    /* use asprintf() because free(evsel) assumes name is allocated */
    if (asprintf(&evsel->name, "cycles%s%s%.*s",
             (attr.precise_ip || attr.exclude_kernel) ? ":" : "",
             attr.exclude_kernel ? "u" : "",
             attr.precise_ip ? attr.precise_ip + 1 : 0, "ppp") < 0)
    return evsel;
}
```

In case of failed perf_event_open (no access to hardware cycles sampling, for example in virtualized environment without virtualized PMU) there is failback to **software cpu-clock** sampling in [tools/perf/builtin-record.c: `int record__open()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/tools/perf/builtin-record.c#L741) which calls [`perf_evsel__fallback()` of tools/perf/util/evsel.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/tools/perf/util/evsel.c#L2330):

```
bool perf_evsel__fallback(struct evsel *evsel, int err,
              char *msg, size_t msgsize)
{
    if ((err == ENOENT || err == ENXIO || err == ENODEV) &&
        evsel->core.attr.type   == PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE &&
        evsel->core.attr.config == PERF_COUNT_HW_CPU_CYCLES) {
        /*
         * If it's cycles then fall back to hrtimer based
         * cpu-clock-tick sw counter, which is always available even if
         * no PMU support.
         */
        scnprintf(msg, msgsize, "%s", "The cycles event is not supported, trying to fall back to cpu-clock-ticks");

        evsel->core.attr.type   = PERF_TYPE_SOFTWARE;
        evsel->core.attr.config = PERF_COUNT_SW_CPU_CLOCK;

        return true;
    } ...
}
```